# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthServiceProvider Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have a small AngularJS project, but for some reason, my service files aren't able to be successfully injected into any of the controllers. Maybe I've made a minor syntax error that I've overlooked, but I've tried several variations:

Service:

```
(function (){

'use strict';

  angular
    .module('tooltipEditorFrontEndApp')
    .factory('AuthService', AuthService);

    AuthService.$inject = ['$window', 'Restangular'];

    function AuthService($window, Restangular) {

      var exports = {
        setAuthHeader: setAuthHeader
      };

      function setAuthHeader() {
        if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
          var token = angular.fromJson($window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')).token;
          Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Token '+token });
        }
      }

      return exports;

    }

})();
```

Controller:

```
(function (){

'use strict';

  angular
    .module('tooltipEditorFrontEndApp')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', 'Restangular', 'AuthService'];

    function MainController($scope, $window, Restangular, AuthService) {

      var test;

      AuthService.setAuthHeader();

      test = Restangular.all('states');

      test.getList().then(function(states) {
        $scope.states = Restangular.stripRestangular(states);
      });
    }

})();
```

Load scripts:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script scr="scripts/services/auth.service.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.controller.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/login.controller.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.controller.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and re-installed Angular 1.4.1 to the project, and now the service works as it should.